# HttpsURLConnection gives connect timeout but working with JS XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I  need to call a database api https://hosturl/query?apiToken=authenticated_API_Token 
and need to pass request payload :-

```
{ "\r\n" +
                    "\"filterString\": \"([62wUXYCDt0WnOnO18psHbQ.ZPyw3IUxsUWvywjWCEuAdQ.QEfefkYB5EqgogjWCEuoBg] ge Today() and Date([62wUXYCDt0WnOnO18psHbQ.ZPyw3IUxsUWvywjWCEuAdQ.KR-iuFdqYUCnjgjW8zNMoQ]) le Today())\",\r\n"
                    "\r\n" +
                    "}
```

It will give a response with post call.

I tried it with JS:-

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlHttp.open("POST", "https://hosturl/query?apiToken=someToken", true);

xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlHttp.send("{ "\r\n" +
                    "\"filterString\": \"([62wUXYCDt0WnOnO18psHbQ.ZPyw3IUxsUWvywjWCEuAdQ.QEfefkYB5EqgogjWCEuoBg] ge Today() and Date([62wUXYCDt0WnOnO18psHbQ.ZPyw3IUxsUWvywjWCEuAdQ.KR-iuFdqYUCnjgjW8zNMoQ]) le Today())\",\r\n"
                    "\r\n" +
                    "}");
```

Here I am getting proper response.

But when I am trying with java getting connection timeout.

```
final URL url = new URL(https://hosturl/query?apiToken=someToken);
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
final String payLoad ="{ "\r\n" +
                    "\"filterString\": \"([62wUXYCDt0WnOnO18psHbQ.ZPyw3IUxsUWvywjWCEuAdQ.QEfefkYB5EqgogjWCEuoBg] ge Today() and Date([62wUXYCDt0WnOnO18psHbQ.ZPyw3IUxsUWvywjWCEuAdQ.KR-iuFdqYUCnjgjW8zNMoQ]) le Today())\",\r\n"
                    "\r\n" +
                    "}";
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json") ;
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(payLoad.length()));
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
final java.io.OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            try (java.io.OutputStreamWriter wr = new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(os);) {
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();
            }

final int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == 200 || responseCode == 201) {
                final StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                try (java.io.BufferedReader in = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
                    String inputLine;
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                }
                responseString = response.toString();
            } else {
            }
conn.disconnect();
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Exception ", ex);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

What can be the reason?